# if no xxhdpi resources are in the folder?

Tags: android, resources, default

if i have resources in all of the folders except the xxhdpi folder will xxhdpi devices take from one of the other folders as a default? in other words do i have to make resources for xxhdpi folder? i have this chart but im not sure of xxhdpi im trying to be enlightened a little

```
xlarge screens are at least 960dp x 720dp
large screens are at least 640dp x 480dp
normal screens are at least 470dp x 320dp
small screens are at least 426dp x 320dp
Generalised Dpi values for screens:

ldpi Resources for low-density (ldpi) screens (~120dpi)
mdpi Resources for medium-density (mdpi) screens (~160dpi). (This is the baseline      density.)
hdpi Resources for high-density (hdpi) screens (~240dpi).
xhdpi Resources for extra high-density (xhdpi) screens (~320dpi).
Therefore generalised size of your resources (assuming they are full screen):

ldpi
Vertical = 426 * 120 / 160 = 319.5px
Horizontal = 320 * 120 / 160 = 240px
mdpi
Vertical = 470 * 160 / 160 = 470px
Horizontal = 320 * 160 / 160 = 320px
hdpi
Vertical = 640 * 240 / 160 = 960px
Horizontal = 480 * 240 / 160 = 720px
xhdpi
Vertical = 960 * 320 / 160 = 1920px
Horizontal = 720 * 320 / 160 = 1440px

px = dp*dpi/160
```

Comment: Answer to your question. Yes it will choose from another folder. So if the device cannot find the xxhdpi image it will go to the xhdpi folder and get it from there. Go have a look at this link for more info http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/screens.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you don't have any xxhdpi resources it will try to take resources from the "best" source possible.

from the [google developer site](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html):

> - The system uses the appropriate alternative resource
>
> Based on the size and density of the current screen, the system uses
>   any size- and density-specific resource provided in your application.
>   For example, if the device has a high-density screen and the
>   application requests a drawable resource, the system looks for a
>   drawable resource directory that best matches the device
>   configuration. Depending on the other alternative resources available,
>   a resource directory with the hdpi qualifier (such as drawable-hdpi/)
>   might be the best match, so the system uses the drawable resource from
>   this directory.
>
> - If no matching resource is available, the system uses
>     the default resource and scales it up or down as needed to match the
>     current screen size and density
>
> The "default" resources are those that are not tagged with a
>   configuration qualifier. For example, the resources in drawable/ are
>   the default drawable resources. The system assumes that default
>   resources are designed for the baseline screen size and density, which
>   is a normal screen size and a medium density. As such, the system
>   scales default density resources up for high-density screens and down
>   for low-density screens, as appropriate.

Comment: so if i only had resources in ldpi, xxhdpi devices would take from that?

Comment: As it says-- it uses the best it can find and adjusts accordingly.  It would really size up those ldpi graphics though.

Comment: Oh yeah, note that it will size the graphics according to its needs.  So if you wanted, for some strange reason, to have the art be the same actual pixel size on all formats, you could copy the exact same art into every density's folder.

Comment: ok, thanks again, i read that on the site i was just a little bit confused about it